# C# Settings file - how to load?

Tags: c#, settings.settings

I have an application where I need to store 3 set of string collections (user bookmarks and some other stuff).  I have added a "Setting File" to my C# project, created the 3 settings variables of type Specialized String Collection.  Everything appears to be fine, as I can add strings to each of the collections and invoke the .Save() method of Settings.Default.  I can see my pretty string collections within the generated "user.config" file.

HOWEVER, when do these values get loaded?  There is no .Load() method of Settings.  Attempting to access the Settings.-setting variable- name throws a null exception error, so obviously these values are not loaded at launch time on their own.

What am I missing?

Comment: They're loaded automatically when you start the program. If you're not seeing what you should be seeing then you'll have to post some code, otherwise nobody here will be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Note also that the settings file must reside in the same directory as the executable program itself.

Comment: The user.config file is stored in \AppData\Local\ directory.  Anyway, I blew away the Settings file in my project and re-created.  Now it's working as intended.  Not sure what happened.  I originally renamed the "Settings1." to a different name after creation -- that possibly had something to do with its wonky behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're having problems with differing versions of the application and settings file? Try calling [`ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade.aspx) to migrate previous settings to a new version.

Note that you should only be calling `Upgrade` once, and only when you've actually updated your settings. Create a settings property called `NeedsUpgrade` with a default value of true, and execute the following when you application loads:

```
if (Settings.Default.NeedsUpgrade)
{
    Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Settings.Default.NeedsUpgrade = false;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

With this, `Upgrade` will only be called when a new version of a settings file is created.